# Got socket error trying to find package get at https://pub.dev

Tags: flutter

I am facing this problem when adding new packages Except "flutter_bloc"

I updated flutter and android studio to the latest version and tested everything by flutter doctor command  and every thing is going well but I still facing this problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's a "DNS problem". Try adding  8.8.8.8 in the Preferred DNS server field and enter 8.8.4.4 in the Alternate DNS server field.
.
.
.
To change your DNS server on a Windows 10, go to

- Settings
- Network & Internet
- Wi-Fi(Tab)
- Change Adapter Settings(right side)
- Then right-click on your current Wi-Fi connection and
- Select Properties
- Look for IPv4(similar)
- Properties

Finally, select **Use the following DNS server** and then field **Preferred DNS server** put `8.8.8.8` in it, and enter `8.8.4.4` in the **Alternate DNS server** field.
.
.
.
This solved the issue of running "`flutter pub get` or `flutter pub upgrade`" for me!
to read more refer to the documentation here: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/troubleshoot#pub-get-socket-error

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much it worked for me:

in windows 11:
go to Settings > Network & Internet > WI-FI > Hardware Properties > More Adapter Options > Click Edit.

Look for IP4, click Properties > Make it "Use The Following DNS Server Address"

Preferred DNS Server : 8.8.8.8
Alternative DNS Server : 8.8.4.4

that worked for me. Thank you A J